# use of new keyword in class declaration

Tags: c#, declaration

Can somebody please explain the use of the new keyword in below code?

```
public class TableList<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : ITable, new()
```

Answer (score 4):

assuming this is C#:

It is a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx), it means that T must have a parameterless constructor

without it you cannot construct a new T()

Answer (score 4):

It's a generics thing. It means that any class used to replace T must have a constructor with no arguments.

ie. With your example, if you write

```
var list = new TableList<Foo>();
```

Foo MUST have a default constructor, or it won't compile.

The reason for doing this is that it allows the author of the TableList class to say

```
var item = new T();
```

and the compiler can translate that (specifically for TableList<Foo>) to mean

```
var item = new Foo();
```

without fear that Foo might not be instantiated through a default constructor.